# trouble with setting my LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside my makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH inside my makefile so that I do not have to run the commands to set it after I do "make all." However, although the command is executed, when I try to use ./driver, I get

> ./driver: error while loading shared libraries: libparser.so: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory.

When I do the command after I get that error (outside of the makefile) it's fixed. Do you have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Here's my Makefile currently:

```
# OPTIONAL: Set these variables as required.
CFLAGS := -g -Wall -std=c99
LDFLAGS :=
LDLIBS :=

all: static-driver driver setenvp

# OPTIONAL: COMPLETE THIS TARGET
# This target produces an object file for making libraries.
parser.o: parser.c
    cc -c -fPIC $(CFLAGS) parser.c

# COMPLETE THIS TARGET
# This target produces the dynamic library.
lib/libparser.so: parser.o
    gcc -shared -o libparser.so parser.o

# COMPLETE THIS TARGET
# This target produces the executable using the dynamic library
driver: driver.c lib/libparser.so
    gcc driver.c -I$(PWD) -L$(PWD)/lib -o driver -lparser

# This target produces the executable using static library
static-driver: driver.c lib/test.a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) driver.c -I$(PWD) lib/test.a -o static-driver

setenvp:
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(PWD)/lib

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -fv static-driver driver
    rm -fv lib/libparser.so
    rm -fv *.o *.txt *.bin
    rm -fv *~ \#*\# *.swp
```

Comment: setenvp should probably be included in the .PHONY since you are not creating a file of that name.

Answer (score 2):

Since every line is executed in a new shell environment, you must 
prefix anything to be inherited before the commands. That is you
might want to define

```
MY_CC := export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(PWD)/lib; gcc
```

and then have your targets be built by

```
target.o: target.c
    $(MY_CC) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using a make variable `PWD` but you've never set it.  The only way this will be set is if your shell sets it and exports it before make is invoked, but it's poor practice to rely on this.  If you really want to refer to the current directory, why not just use `.` instead of `$(PWD)`?  It's more reliable.

Second, environment variables are an attribute of the current process, in UNIX.  When you change the environment variables in a given process, those changes will be passed down to any new children created by the process after the change is made.

But, it's not actually possible for a child process to change the environment of its parent.

Every make recipe is run in a new child process (a shell process).

So, your target here:

```
setenvp:
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib
```

will essentially run `/bin/sh -c 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib'` which will start a shell, have the subshell set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in its environment, then exit the subshell whereupon the environment change is gone.  So this is a no-op: it just takes up time while having no effect.

In fact there is no way to have make change the environment of the shell that invoked it, because make is a child process of your shell and thus make cannot change your shell's environment.

Comment: *"it's not actually possible for a child process to change the environment of its parent"* -- it's those core concepts that seem to escape a number of posters. It isn't covered that well in documentation either, e.g. [Chapter 21. Subshells](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html). Strange...